# Merge Files in a directory c#

Tags: c#

I have many text files in a directory and I need to merge them into one

I tried the following code

```
File.WriteAllLines(
    outputFileName,
    Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.txt")
        .SelectMany(f =>
            File.ReadLines(f).Concat(new[] { Environment.NewLine })));
```

It works fine but my problem is that I get empty blank lines between the content of each file . Is there a way to modify it in order to get a text file without those empty lines ?

Comment: What if you remove `Concat(new[] { Environment.NewLine })` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel that should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @ClickRick Does it worth to be a answer?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'd say it's **the** answer.

Comment: @ClickRick Added as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment as an answer on request.

It seems you're concatenating `Environment.NewLine` at end of each file, which adds the new line between the content of each file. If that's not what you need why do you use that statement?

Removing `Concat(new[] { Environment.NewLine })` should yield the expected result.

```
var allLines = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.txt")
                        .SelectMany(f => File.ReadLines(f));
File.WriteAllLines(outputFileName, allLines);
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace `Environment.NewLine` with `String.Empty`

Comment: All lines from the same file would end up as one long line.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden I don't think so, `File.ReadLines` takes care of that.

Comment: Despite of 3 upvotes this answer doesn't deserves it. Why do you need `String.Empty` there? Concatenating `String.Empty` with "some string" will be same as "some string". so you don't need a `Concat` at all!.

Comment: Ok, I should have tested before making that comment.

Comment: @Sriram Yeah, I agree. When I read the OP the first time I read the Concat statement as the join. Your solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code :

```
string[] txtFiles;
        txtFiles = Directory.GetFiles(txtFileDestination.Text, "*.txt");
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(txtFileDestination.Text + @"\allfiles.txt"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < txtFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(txtFiles[i]))
                {
                    writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
```